# Unix Environment Variable Not displaying correctly

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, public-key-encryption

I am implementing public private key based authentication and I need to parameters the location where I store my keys. So that, programmatically my jobs can read it from this location and establish the authentication.

I added the below line in the file `/etc/profile`.
`export PRIVATE_KEYS_PATH=<Some_Path>`

I logged out of terminal and logged back in and I could see the value of the above variable using either of the commands
`echo $PRIVATE_KEYS_PATH` or `env`

However, same is not getting displayed when I am running either of the commands on Visual Studio Code. Any idea ? Is there a better place where I can mention this environment variable

PS: I am using bash.

Comment: not sure you are going about this the right way.  i'd recommend reading https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen, in particular how to add keys to your agent

Comment: VS Code is not inheriting *its* environment from a shell that processes `/etc/profile` (or indeed, *any* shell).

Comment: @chepner
We use airflow (workflow orchestration tool from Apache) and even Airflow is not reading this value. What would you suggest in this scenario ?

Comment: I'm on team "keys should be stored in an agent". It's _deeply_ bad practice to expose them in a way that lets software make a copy of the key material itself; the better approaches don't even store the private key anywhere your computer can read them, but have a separate piece of hardware (like a [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/) on the low end, or a [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) on the high end) that runs signature operations when the general-purpose computer requests it.

Comment: ...when you pass around a path to a private key on-disk, or even worse write your software to pass the key material around, you're designing that software in such a way that it _can't_ offload the work to dedicated hardware.

Comment: You might get better answers on superuser.com.

Comment: Do you work somewhere with a security team? Talk to them; they'll have relevant advice. (Bigger companies often have their HSMs centralized, with process and tooling available to authorize specific operations within specific time ranges, etc; writing tools that don't support that infrastructure can be a policy violation)